# Add yii2 event handler in model itself

Tags: yii, yii2, swiftmailer

In my user model I need to send email after inserting a new record. I can't wait exicution for sending email, because it take too much time. So I tried to use Event handler inside Model itself

```
class User extends ActiveRecord {
    public function events()
    {
        return [
            User::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT => [$this, 'sendEmail']
        ];
    }
     public function sendEmail(){
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setTo($this->email)
            ->setFrom(['mail address' => 'name'])
            ->setSubject('Verify your Email')
            ->setHtmlBody('<p>Please click on the <a href="'.Yii::$app->request->hostInfo.'/'.Yii::$app->params['frontEndUrl'].'#/verify-email/'
                .$this->emailToken.
                '">link</a> to verify your email</p>')
            ->send();
    }
}
```

But it is not working any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You probably come from a javascript background, but events in PHP do not work that way (in Javascript it does). If you raise an event it will get caught but not in a new process. Even if you manage to do what you want it will still wait for the email to be sent out.

The solution would be to use some sort of queue, the simplest one just insert a record in an "email" table in the DB and move on. You can have a cronjob that processes the email table and sends out the actual emails.

Comment: It is a email verification so I can't set it as CRON job. Is there any other method to send email, other than swift mail, like mandrill ?

Comment: Of course you can send it as a cron. What are the technical / logical consideration why you cannot? Also of course you can use mandrill I used this one in the past. https://packagist.org/packages/nickcv/yii2-mandrill

Comment: can you give me an example for setting cron job , how can I send email instantly whenever new user record inserted.

Comment: These 2 words "email instantly" should never go together. Email is not instant by definition. If sending emails takes too much time either use mandril or insert the content of the emails in an "email" table. Make a cronjob process that table every minute to send the emails. The cronjob can be slow just make sure it does not take more than 1 minute. If you never did this before use mandril, it will save you days of problems that the cronjob itself will bring up. It costs money now, if that is a problem try to find another free alternative.